# How i can trigger a function after animating done?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I am using `React-native-reanimated` and `react-native-gesture-handler`,
I need to trigger a function after animation done, This is my my code:

```js
  let a = new Value(1);
  let onStateChange = event([
    {
      nativeEvent: ({state}) =>
        block([
          cond(
            eq(state, State.END),
            set(a, runTiming(new Clock(), 1, 0)),
          ),
        ]),
    },
  ]);

return <TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={onStateChange}>
```

I need something like this :

```js
      onStateChange = event => {
        if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
          alert("I'm being pressed");
        }
        return block([
          cond(
            eq(event.nativeEvent.state, State.END),
            set(a, runTiming(new Clock(), 1, 0)),
          ),
        ]);
      },
```

But not works. :/

Comment: all you need is more cond and call functions from reanimated

Comment: @AbdumutalAbdusamatov I tried but calling function inside condition not works properly, When i replace ```set``` with ```console.warn``` it triggers on first component render always, not on end of tapping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `call` method to handle back from native section to JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`call`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/nodes/call) method once the animation is finished (`state.END`).

This example is for normal animation but the implementation for your case should be similar, notice that when you use `call` you can pass back parameters to the function you want to use.

```js
function runTiming({ clock, value, dest, afterAnimationActions }) {
  const state = {
    finished: new Value(0),
    position: value,
    time: new Value(0),
    frameTime: new Value(0),
  };

  const config = {
    duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
    toValue: dest,
    easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
  };

  return block([
    cond(clockRunning(clock), 0, [
      set(state.finished, 0),
      set(state.time, 0),
      set(state.position, value),
      set(state.frameTime, 0),
      set(config.toValue, dest),
      startClock(clock),
    ]),
    timing(clock, state, config),
    cond(state.finished, [
      stopClock(clock),
      call([dest], (d) => afterAnimationActions(d)), // <-- Add this
    ]),
    state.position,
  ]);
}
```

With that, you can call `runTiming` like this:

```js
transY = runTiming({
    clock: this.clock,
    value: this.from,
    dest: this.toValue,
    afterAnimationActions: this.afterAnimationActions,
});
```

And the afterAnimationActions should look like this:

```js
afterAnimationActions = ([dest]) => {
    // `dest` is the param we passed using `call`
    // The function logic here
};
```